# Centre text in leaflet popup on marker

Tags: r, popup, leaflet, marker

I am currently using leaflet to create a map and I was wondering if it was possible to centre the text in a popup?

[Here is an example of what a marker currently looks like, as you can see, the writing below starts from the left and I was hoping there's a way to centre the second line.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ba484.png)

This is the code I am currently using it for it:

```
map <- leaflet(nodes) %>% addTiles() %>% setView(-0.219067099999961, 51.5122826, zoom=15) %>% addAwesomeMarkers(~lng, ~lat, icon=icons, popup = paste(nodes$group, "<br>", nodes$label))
```

Answer (score 2):

Create css class and apply to popup text

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Demo</title>
    <style>
    #map {
        height: 600px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
    }

 .myCss{
 text-align:center;
 }
 </style>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.0.3/dist/MarkerCluster.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.0.3/dist/MarkerCluster.Default.css" />
 <link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-fullscreen/v1.0.1/leaflet.fullscreen.css' rel='stylesheet' />


</head>

<body>
<div id="map"></div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.markercluster-src.js"></script>
<script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-fullscreen/v1.0.1/Leaflet.fullscreen.min.js'></script>
<script>
    var addressPoints = [
        [-31.953512, 115.857048, "<p class='myCss'><b>Morgan Stanley<br> Funder</b><p>"],
        [-37.8210819833, 175.2213903167, "<p class='myCss'><b>Morgan Stanley<br> Funder</b><p>"],
        [-34.206841, 142.136490, "<p class='myCss'><b>Morgan Stanley<br> Funder</b><p>"],
        [-37.8211946833, 175.2213655333, "<p class='myCss'><b>Morgan Stanley<br> Funder</b><p>"]
    ];
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var tiles = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {});
        latlng = L.latLng(-25.2744, 133.7751);

    var map = L.map('map', {center: latlng,
        zoom: 4,
        layers: [tiles],
        fullscreenControl: {
            pseudoFullscreen: false
        }
    });

    var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();

    for (var i = 0; i < addressPoints.length; i++) {
        var a = addressPoints[i];
        var title = a[2];
        var marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(a[0], a[1]), { title: title });
        marker.bindPopup(title);
        markers.addLayer(marker);
    }
    map.addLayer(markers);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If it worked, [please mark the answer as accepted.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) Thanks!